# Rails and Devise: Error with namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

What I need is that when a user goes to '/admin', it redirects to '/admins/sign_in' for the user to sign in.

This is what I did:

```
# routes.rb

devise_for :admins

namespace :admin do
  root to: 'users#index'
end
```

.

```
# controllers/admin/base_controller.rb

class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  layout 'admin'
end
```

.

```
# controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
  def index
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I go to '/admin' it returns me an error:

> NoMethodError in Admin::UsersController#index ..
>   undefined method `authenticate_user!' for Admin::UsersController

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have nearly the same setup as you, and it works perfectly:

[image]

I think the problem is that you're using `devise_for :admins`, and yet calling `authenticate_user!`; it should be `authenticate_admin!` (as per the [Devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-multiple-models)):

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!
end
```

Comment: Whoops. Missed that typo.